# "RS Add-In for SharePoint" Server Consistency

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, reporting-services

I just noticed on a SP2010 Farm that I am working on some servers have the "Microsoft SQL Server 2012 RS Add-in for SharePoint" installed while others do not . That feature is not being used in this environment so I want to remove it because one of the servers showing ULS errors complaining it is missing feature xml files related to Reporting Services.

To clear those ULS error messages, is it safe to remove the Add-in for all servers or would it be best to just install in on the servers missing it?

Comment: are you using the RS in your farm?

Comment: No we are not using RS in the farm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not using the RS then I dont think any reason to keep it and flood ULS logs with the errors.

You can uninstall it using the Add/remove program or using the command line tools.
Like this

```
msiexec.exe /uninstall rsSharePoint.msi
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905871.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#bkmk_remove_addin

Comment: Yes i saw this article. It does not say anything about if uninstalling requires reboot.

Comment: reboot? i dont think you asked this before? I am sure, uninstalling does not need reboot.

Comment: You are right, I did not - curious. I just did it on stage and no reboot was required. I was wondering in my original quesiton if it would be safer to add it to the servers which don't have it or remove it from those which do.  Perhaps there is no difference but with SharePoint somethings like this cause unexpected consequences.